# PHP and form handling

Tags: php, mysql, forms, textbox, wamp

I have been working with PHP and MySQL for about two months and I recently began using forms. I have a main form-processing file:

```
if($_POST['checkforpothole'] == "yes"){
    echo "thank you for your help"."<br/>";
    echo "please enter in a latitude and longitude"."<br/>";
    include 'FormForGettingLatAndLong.php';
    $Lat = $_POST['latitude'];
    $Long = $_POST['longitude'];
    include 'MySQLSample.php';
    echo addCoord($Lat, $Long);
    include 'MySQLSample.php';
    die();
}

if($_POST["checkforpothole"] == "no"){
    echo "here is the table"."<br/>";
    include 'MySQLSample.php';
    die();
}
?>
```

The form I am attempting to access is as follows:

```
<?php
?>
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<body>

<form action="FormProcessing.php" method="post">
Latitude: <input type="text" name="latitude"><br>
Longitude: <input type = "text" name = "longitude"><br>
<input type="submit">

</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is the checkforpothole form:

```
<?php

?>
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<body>

<form action="FormProcessing.php" method="post">
Add a new pothole? (yes or no): <input type="text" name="checkforpothole"><br>
<input type="submit">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

I am having trouble accessing latitude and longitude in this form, which is in a separate file. Is there a way to access an index from a second form after accessing from another form initially. Please let me know if there is a problem in the first program, specifically with the first if statement.

Comment: you do not have a input type for checkforpothole. So how is it supposed to get into that line if it doesnt even exist?

Comment: You have no `checkforpothole` form field, so your "get lat/long" stuff will never run. Nor will the "here is the form", since an undefined value, by definition, has no value, so you can't check it against any other value.

Comment: Why didn't you add the `checkforpothole` to your other form?

Comment: Modern PHP development encourages the use of a [development framework](http://codegeekz.com/best-php-frameworks-for-developers/) like [Laravel](http://laravel.com/)  that gives you a solid foundation for building your application. Find one that suits your style and needs and follow the examples and documentation. Most have a large library of community code you can add in with little effort, avoiding the need to reinvent the wheel. What I see here is quickly turning into unmaintainable code stew.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, I think the logic of your code needs a bit of revision.

> ```
> if($_POST['checkforpothole'] == "yes"){
>     echo "thank you for your help"."<br/>";
>     echo "please enter in a latitude and longitude"."<br/>";
>     include 'FormForGettingLatAndLong.php';
>     $Lat = $_POST['latitude'];
>     $Long = $_POST['longitude'];
>     include 'MySQLSample.php';
>     echo addCoord($Lat, $Long);
>     include 'MySQLSample.php';
>     die();
> }
>
> if($_POST["checkforpothole"] == "no"){
>     echo "here is the table"."<br/>";
>     include 'MySQLSample.php';
>     die();
> }
> ?>
> ```

As i concluded from your code it appears that you want to get additional information using a second form when user submitted the first form. and you're trying to do so by including the second form when you are processing the first form and then immediately reading the values of second form:

> ```
>     include 'FormForGettingLatAndLong.php';
>     $Lat = $_POST['latitude'];
>     $Long = $_POST['longitude'];
> ```

but this way, you won't have the Longitude and Latitude! because you just posted the second form to user to get that data! and when she posts back the second form, execution of your code will start from beginning (in a separate process).  working with forms is not like conventional input procedures (like old "cin<<" , "fscanf()" or "System.console().readLine()"). instead you should print the second form and wait for user to submit that.

so you can do what you want using these three files:

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<body>

<form action="firstFormProcessing.php" method="post">
Add a new pothole? (yes or no): <input type="text" name="checkforpothole"><br>
<input type="submit">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

firstFormProcessing.php:

```
<?php
if($_POST['checkforpothole'] == "yes"){
    echo "thank you for your help"."<br/>";
    echo "please enter in a latitude and longitude"."<br/>";
echo <<<END
    <!DOCTYPE HTML>
    <html>
    <body>

    <form action="secondFormProcessing.php" method="post">
    Latitude: <input type="text" name="latitude"><br>
    Longitude: <input type = "text" name = "longitude"><br>
    <input type="submit">

    </form>
    </body>
    </html>
END;
    die();
}

if($_POST["checkforpothole"] == "no"){
    echo "here is the table"."<br/>";
    include 'MySQLSample.php';
    die();
}
?>
```

secondFormProcessing.php:

```
<?php
    echo "now i have Latitude=$_POST[latitude] and Longitude=$_POST[longitude]";
?>
```

P.S. it's my first Answer on stackoverflow. i hope this will help you and by the way sorry for my bad English.

Comment: This works very well! Thank you so much for all the hard work you put into this. It works very well.

Answer (score 0):

I would take 2 files instead of messing on one page, this is how I would do it.
If this helps you then don't forget to mark the question as answered.

**index.php**

```
<?php 

    if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === "POST") {
        if(isset($_POST['checkForPothole'])) {
            if($_POST['checkForPothole'] == true) {
                header("Location: addPole.php");
            }
        }
    }

?>

<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<body>
<form action="index.php" method="post">
    Add a new pothole? (yes or no): <input type="text" name="checkForPothole"><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

**addPole.php**

```
<?php 

    if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === "POST") {
        if(isset($_POST['latitude']) && isset($_POST['longitude'])) {
            if(!empty($_POST['latitude']) && !empty($_POST['longitude']) {
                require_once("MySQLSample.php");

                $latitude = $_POST['latitude'];
                $longitude = $_POST['longitude'];

                addCoord($latitude, $longitude); //guessing that this is a function in the mysqlsample file
            }
        }
    }

?>

<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<body>
<form action="FormProcessing.php" method="post">
    Latitude: <input type="text" name="latitude"><br>
    Longitude: <input type="text" name="longitude"><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: And where is the answer for OP's question?

Comment: I thought that I should use two forms so I could work in stages instead of having all the different input areas visible at once when I do not need them. Also when I submit yes or no to the checkforpothole code, if the user did not put anything in the latitude and longitude areas that they are not using, there is the possibility of blank latitude and longitude to be added to the mysql database I have created, which I want to avoid. Do you have any other suggestions for how I might be able to pull this off? Thank you.

Comment: @MathieuLebiere So you wanna submit a form with 2 textboxes, both latitude and longitude. And from there you wanna submit it to FormProcessing.php and check if the latitude and longitude are set. Then after that it has to insert the values in the database?

Comment: @Jordy That is correct. First I want to submit the checkforpothole form(this can be found at the end of my original post). After I get a yes from this form, I want to go through the second form and add the latitude and longitude into the database as you have described.

Comment: I changed the answer for you, I hope this helps. @MathieuLebiere

Comment: Thank you very much. I will take a closer look and let you know if I have any questions. @Jordy

Comment: @MathieuLebiere Sure, if it has helped you in the end then mark the  answer as answered by clicking on the check next to my post :) That helps me out as well.